# How to have the caller ID displayed on a smartwatch call notification using the ConnectionService API?

Tags: android, voip-android, android-connectionservice

I have a problem integrating a VoIP application with Android smartwatch (any model). Our app uses Android ConnectionService API. 
The caller name is not displayed at the watch's incoming call notification - it simply writes "Unknown" or the caller id (4-digit extension), never the actual app contact name (app contact, not device contact).
However, regular GSM calls are properly displayed (it resolves against the contact name) and also, if someone from my device contacts calls me, their name & avatar are being displayed correctly.

To assign the name I'm using android.telecom.Connection.setCallerDisplayName(displayName, TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED), but to no avail.

Comment: Also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/64425303/3496570

Comment: hi, did you figure out how to solve this? I am having same issue.

Comment: nope. seems a limitation of the API and poor watch integration

Comment: same here... any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue with Samsung Gear smartwatch. You see "Unknown" because the caller's name is resolved against device contacts (hence regular GSM calls work as expected). The solution is following:

1. I assume that you know the `displayName` (caller's name) and `address` (caller's phone number). The address is the Uri which might look like `sip:1234567` or `tel:+1234567`, it doesn't really matter.
2. You need to create a temporary contact with your caller's `displayName` and `phoneNumber`. The `phoneNumber` here should be `Uri.schemeSpecificPart` of the address (the part after `:`). The avatar/icon can also be added.

```
ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, displayName)
                        .build()
```

```
ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
                        .build()
```

3. After adding this contact you need to let `ConnectionService` know that there is now a contact that corresponds to the Connection you created for your VoIP call. `contactManager` is my class where aforementioned operations are executed, `accountHandle` is a `android.telecom.AccountHandle` that is used to
   register `PhoneAccount` (via `telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount()`), `address` is our Uri with phone number.

```
contactManager.createOrUpdateTempContact(address.schemeSpecificPart, displayName)

telecomManager.addNewIncomingCall(accountHandle, bundleOf("key.call.address" to address))
```

4. After calling `addNewIncomingCall` the `ConnectionService::onCreateIncomingConnection()` callback will be triggered, and in this function you should set the address:

```
override fun onCreateIncomingConnection(
    connectionManagerPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle?, 
    request: ConnectionRequest?
): Connection {

    val newConnection = // Instantiate your Connection class implementation

    request?.let{
        newConnection.setAddress(request.extras.getParcelable("key.call.address") as? Uri, TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED)
        newConnection.extras = request.extras
    }

    // Setting up newConnection further (set audioModeIsVoip, connectionProperties, etc.)

    return newConnection
}
```

5. You can safely remove the temp contact after the call was answered/rejected.

**N.B.**

- I omitted posting the whole create/update/delete temp contact code for brevity.
- `ConnectionRequest.address` returns `null` for me in `onCreateIncomingConnection()`, that's why I pass it in `extras`.
- I played with `setCallerDisplayName()` function and the common sense says that it *should* be there, but the fix was not related to it.
- In my experience sometimes the incoming call UI on the smartwatch shows phone number first and only after few seconds the name of the contact is displayed. I still didn't manage to fix this delay.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution. I had a hunch that the ContentProvider should be used, but oddly it seems to be undocumented.