# Can I register Web RTC app as Calling app

Tags: android, telecommunication, webrtc-android, android-phone-call

> I have web rtc implemented in a webview. Everything working fine as long as app in foreground.

Now if the app is in **background/dose** mode. I want to show a **ringing screen like what's app**.
I am having a push notification when some one calls.

I know I can show notification alnog with calling sound and onClick of the notification . I can show my app Activity.

*Is there any call urls exist like* [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430045/how-to-register-some-url-namespace-myapp-app-start-for-accessing-your-progr)

and can it be **handled without notification**

Or can I register my app as calling app. So that whenever call happens I register [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService)

and recieve `onCreateIncomingConnection`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I use janus gateway and my code parts is accordingly,

1. receive firebase message.

   ```
        if(!remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("hangup")){
            print(remoteMessage.getData());
            try {
                Application.shared.pushMessage = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                Application.shared.sipClient = new SipPluginHandler(null,true);
                Application.shared.action = "incoming";
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{
            Application.shared.action = "hangup";
          //  Application.shared.voipPlugin.endCall(Application.shared.uuid);
          Application.shared.voipPlugin = null;
        }
   ```

SipPluginHanler is where my app connects websocket then initilizes webrtc and send receive jsep operations performed.

2. After initilizing handler and establishing websocket connection  process  firebase message.

public void claimSuccess() {

```
    JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    if (fromConnectionService){

        if(Application.shared.action == "incoming"){
            JSONObject message = Application.shared.pushMessage;

            if (message != null){
                putData(result,"event","incomingcall");

                try {
                    String caller =  message.getString("caller_id");
                    putData(result,"username", "sip:" + caller + "@" + connectionInfo.ulakCagriIp);
                    putData(result,"displayname", caller);
                    putData(msg,"janus","event");


                    JSONObject dtdt = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject dt = new JSONObject();

                    putData(dtdt,"result",result);

                    putData(dt,"data",dtdt);

                   putData(msg,"plugindata",dt);


                    JSONObject extra = message.getJSONObject("extra");

                    if (extra != null){
                        JSONObject jsep = extra.getJSONObject("jsep");
                        putData(msg,"jsep", jsep);

                        JanusMessage mesg = JanusMessage.fromJson(msg);
                       onEvent(mesg);


                    }




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }





        }else{

            putData(result,"event", "hangup");
            putData(msg,"janus", "event");
            JSONObject dtdt = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject dt = new JSONObject();

            putData(dtdt,"result",result);

            putData(dt,"data",dtdt);

            putData(msg,"plugindata",dt);

            JanusMessage mesg = JanusMessage.fromJson(msg);
            onEvent(mesg);


        }

    }
}
```

3. in on event there is switch case  that checks events comes from janus gateway.

   ```
    switch (eventType) {
               case accepted:
               updateUI(eventType);
                   onAccepted();
                   break;
               case calling:
               break;
               case declining:
               break;
               case declined:
                  onHangup();
                   onDeclined();
                   updateUI(eventType);
                   break;
               case hangup:
               onHangup();
               updateUI(eventType);

                   if (result.code != 0 && (result.code == 486 || result.code == 503) ){
                       incallManager.stop("_DTMF_");
                   } else{ incallManager.stop();
                       //incallManagerPlugin.stopRingtone();
                   }
               break;
               case incall:
               break;
               case incomingcall:

                 onIncomingCall(result);
                  updateUI(eventType);
                   break;
               case proceeding:
               updateUI(eventType);
                   onPorceeding();
                   break;
               case progress:
               break;
               case registered:
               onRegistered(message);

                   break;
               case registering:
               break;
               case registration_failed:
               break;
               case ringing:
               break;

           }
   ```
4. finally onIncoming function I check if handler class fromConnection is true then I call ConnectionService.

   ```
    private void onIncomingCall(JanusMessage.JanusResult result) 
       {
            Application.shared.text = result.displayname.replace("\"","");

     if(fromConnectionService){
        Application.shared.voipPlugin = new VoipPlugin();

        uuid = createTransactionID();
        Application.shared.uuid = uuid;
       Application.shared.voipPlugin.reportIncomingCall(uuid,Application.shared.text,Application.shared.text);
      }
   }
   ```

for connection service classes I just modified android part of a flutter plugin below.
https://github.com/BradenBagby/flutter_voip_kit/tree/master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flutter_voip_kit